# Need help moving and renaming files using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I am working on a script that I need to do the following: 
In the working folder I have a folder structure like this:

- A

  - 1
  - 2
- B

  - 1
  - 2

There are files in the root folder that need to be moved into these folders based on the file name. A file name example would be "A, 1~ 1001-Text". The script I have (below) will currently move this file into Folder "A", and rename the file "1~ 1001-Text", using the comma as delimiter.

```
Dim fso
Dim CurrentFolder
Dim Files
Dim NewFolderName
Dim TruncatedFileName
Dim NewFileName
Dim aString
Dim Array

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set CurrentFolder = fso.GetFolder(".")
Set Files = CurrentFolder.Files

For Each File in Files
   If UCase(Right(File.Name,3)) <> "VBS" Then
  TruncatedFileName = Left(File.Name, InstrRev(File.Name, ", ") - 1)
    aString = File.Name
    Array = Split(aString,", ")
    NewFileName = Trim(Array(1))
  File.Move TruncatedFileName & "\"
  fso.MoveFile TruncatedFileName & "\" & File.Name, TruncatedFileName & "\" & NewFileName
   End If
Next
```

What I need is for the code to then take the file "1~ 1001-Text" in folder "A", move it in to the sub folder "1", and rename the file "1001-Text", using "~" as the delimiter.
I have tried creating 2 of each variable and just duplicating the code in the For Next statement, but this does not work... any suggestions? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong : Did you want for example if you have X~Y-Text files,you should create a folder named X and move into this later this file while renaming it to Y-Text ?

Comment: The file structure is already in place, all folders already exist. File "A, 1~ 1001-Text" ultimately needs to end up in A>1>"1001-Text"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this .... (not tested)

```
Dim fso
Dim CurrentFolder
Dim Files
Dim Array1
Dim Array2

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set CurrentFolder = fso.GetFolder(".")
Set Files = CurrentFolder.Files

For Each File in Files


If UCase(Right(File.Name,3)) <> "VBS" Then 'only do non .vbs files

    Array1 = Split(File.Name, ", ") ' split the filename based on the ,

    If (Len(Array1(0)) = 1) Then ' if the first part was a value single character (folder name) 

        Array2 = Split(Array1(1), "~ ") ' now split the second part of the filename

        If (Len(Array2(0)) = 1) And (IsNumeric(Array2(0))) Then ' if it had a valid single number value numeric folder name

            fso.MoveFile(File, Trim(Array1(0)) & "\" & Trim(Array2(0)) & "\" & Trim(Array2(1))) ' do the move

        Else

            MsgBox("Could not parse '~ ' from file '" & File.Name & "'")

        End If

    Else

        MsgBox("Could not parse ', ' from file '" & File.Name & "'")

    End If

End If

Next

Set CurrentFolder = Nothing
Set Files = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: This gives a "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub" error at 24,97. I am very new to VBScript and am not sure how to fix this, but I will try out different ideas with this. Also, The folder "A" is just an example, and the folders will vary greatly in character length.

Comment: EDIT: I removed the outermost parentheses and the 2 nested If/Then statements and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: No problem - I keep forgetting about no parenthesis in vbs... :-)   glad it worked.